# Reversing a List before passing it as an argument

Tags: algorithm, list, haskell

I'm fairly new at Haskell and I've been trying to workaround a solution for a while now, but I can't seem to be getting anywhere.

I have defined a data type called Binary recursively

```
data Binary = BaseOne | Zero Binary | One Binary
```

And I'm trying to make a function that takes a binary number in list form (i.e. [1, 1, 0, 1] and converts it to my data type Binary.

```
binListaBin :: [Int] -> Binary
binListaBin []              = error "Empty List."
binListaBin [1]             = BaseOne
binListaBin x:xs
            | x == 0    = Zero (binListaBin xs)
            | x == 1    = One  (binListaBin xs)
            | otherwise = error "Not a binary."
```

The problem is that my function gives the result reversed, so my guess is that if I can reverse the input list before the function works with it, it should work properly, but I don't know how to do that inside the function. I have tried toying around with *where* and *let* sentences, but can't seem to be getting it right.

Comment: What exactly is this function supposed to mean? I find it deeply suspicious that `[0]` and `[1]` yield the same results, and that `[]` is rejected.

Comment: That's just because I'm not considering 0 as a binary.

Comment: @AdriánRodríguez That makes no sense.

Comment: Proposal for a complete rewrite: `binListaBin = map (0/=)`. Only half joking.

Comment: Edited it so [0] is no longer an expected input.

Comment: What about even numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```hs
import Data.List (foldl') -- strict foldl

data Binary = BaseOne     -- The leading one in front of all binary numbers
            | Zero Binary -- Zero followed by a string of binary digits
            | One Binary  -- One followed by a string of binary digits
            deriving Show

toBinary :: Int -> Binary -> Binary
toBinary 0 = Zero
toBinary 1 = One

flipToBinary :: Binary -> Int -> Binary
flipToBinary = flip toBinary

foldBinary :: [Int] -> Binary
foldBinary (1:xs) = foldl' flipToBinary BaseOne xs
```

Let's look at an example. We'll use my favorite number 11 in binary represented as a `[Int]`:

```
  8 + 0 + 2 + 1 = 11

[ 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 ]
```

The `foldBinary` function converts it to the `Binary` representation:

```hs
foldBinary [1,0,1,1] = One (One (Zero BaseOne))
```

In `Binary` it is represented as `One (One (Zero BaseOne))`. Backwards is forwards.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the list before you pass it to your `binListaBin` function by creating an alias function.

```
binListaBin xs = binListaBinInner $ reverse xs

binListaBinInner :: [Int] -> Binary
binListaBinInner []              = error "Empty List."
binListaBinInner [0]             = BaseOne
binListaBinInner [1]             = BaseOne
binListaBinInner x:xs
            | x == 0    = Zero (binListaBinInner xs)
            | x == 1    = One  (binListaBinInner xs)
            | otherwise = error "Not a binary."
```